# Count xml multiple child tag in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

My XML is looks like this :

```
<a>
   <b>b1</b>
   <c>c1</c>
   <d>
       <x>apple1</x>
       <y>orange1</y>
       <z>Mango1</z>
   </d>
   <d>
       <x>apple2</x>
       <y>orange2</y>
       <z>Mango2</z>
   </d>
   <d>
       <x>apple3</x>
       <y>orange3</y>
       <z>Mango3</z>
   </d>
</a>
<a>
   <b>b2</b>
   <c>c2</c>
   <d>
       <x>apple4</x>
       <y>orange4</y>
       <z>Mango4</z>
   </d>
   <d>
       <x>apple5</x>
       <y>orange5</y>
       <z>Mango5</z>
   </d>
</a>
```

Here i want to count the number of `<d>...</d>` tag in each `<a>...</a>` in objectiveC. The answer will be 3 for first `<a>` tag and 2 for second `<a>` tag. Please give me a suggestion. Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
        currentBook = [[BookListInfo alloc] init];
        currentNodeContentBook=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        isInChapterDTO = false;
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"d"])
    {
    //currentBook = [[BookListInfo alloc] init];
    currentNodeContentChapters=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    isInChapterDTO = true;
    currentChapter = [[Chapters alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if(isInChapterDTO==TRUE)
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"x"])
        {
            currentChapter.chapterId = currentNodeContentChapters;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"y"])
        {
            NSString*appendString=@"B";
            currentNodeContentChapters=[appendString   stringByAppendingString:currentNodeContentChapters];
        currentChapter.chapterName = currentNodeContentChapters;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"z"])
        {
            currentChapter.chapterDurationAsSec = currentNodeContentChapters;
        }
}
    else
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"b"])
        {
            [currentNodeContentBook stringByAppendingString:currentNodeContentBook];
        currentBook.bookId = currentNodeContentBook;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"c"])
        {
            ......................
        }
    }
}
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"a"])
{
    [bookListArray addObject:currentBook];
    currentBook = nil;
    currentNodeContentBook = nil;
}
else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"d"])
{
    [chapterListArray addObject:currentChapter];
    //currentBook.ChapterList.Add(currentChapter);
    currentChapter = nil;
    isInChapterDTO = false;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion #1: this is not related to Xcode. Suggestion #2: use an XML parser and an `int`.

Comment: i use XMLParser and use counter for it. But can't manage it. Let me add the ObjC Code here. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @Tulon your tags are always paired? no need to check right?

Comment: @Chancy which tag are you talking about? <b> & <c> ? Then yes. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Tulon i mean <a></a>,<b></b>,  there is no such case like only <b> no </b>.

Comment: no no, they are all paired. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int dCount;
BOOL isATag;

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
        isATag = YES;
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"d"])
    {
        if(isATag){
            dCount++;
        }
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"a"]){
        NSLog(@"d tag count between A: %d",dCount);
        dCount=0;
        isATag = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me "0" output.

Comment: @Tulon there is some type error. but it output the first 3 in my test.

Comment: Thanks for you all effort @Chancy :)
By the way, i think you all missing one thing. Here i use a BOOL type "isInChapterDTO" in "didEndElement" & i pickup the values of both tag "a" and "d" using this condition.

So, there is no "if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"a"])" in "didEndElement".
Though i put the codes like this, but not working.

The code : (please copy and past this code in xcode if not seeing clearly)

Comment: Here is the code : 

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
        currentBook = [[BookListInfo alloc] init];
        currentNodeContentBook=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        isInChapterDTO = false;
        isATag = YES;
    }

Comment: else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"d"])
 {
        currentChapter = [[Chapters alloc] init];
        currentNodeContentChapters=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        isInChapterDTO = true;
        if(isATag){
            dCount++;
        }
 }
}

Comment: - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if(isInChapterDTO==FALSE)
    {
        NSLog(@"d tag count between A: %d",dCount);
        dCount=0;
        isATag = NO;

Comment: if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"b"])
  {
            [currentNodeContentBook stringByAppendingString:currentNodeContentBook];
   currentBook.bookKey = currentNodeContentBook;
  }
  if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"c"])
  {
            [currentNodeContentBook stringByAppendingString:currentNodeContentBook];
   currentBook.orderLineKey = currentNodeContentBook;
  }

Comment: @Tulon haha,its crazy to paste codes in comments;). Anyway i hope you can work it out. and if my answer is helpful, please accept it :).

Answer (score 1):

Declare the below objects

```
int count;
BOOL insideATag;
NSMutableArray *dCounts;
```

Initialize the *dCounts* in *viewDidLoad*

```
dCounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Add the below delegate methods

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
        insideATag = YES;
        count = 0;
    }

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   if ([element isEqualToString:@"a"]){
        insideATag = NO;
        [dCounts addObject:count]
    } else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"d"] && insideATag)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

If you want count of 'd' tags inside first 'a' tag, then

```
NSLog(@"Count of d  : %i",[dCounts objectAtIndex:0]);
```